# Form not passing values on POST (popup box)

Tags: php, jquery, html, mobile

My form is not passing any values when I submit it. I am not too sure what is wrong with it. Can anyone spot my mistake(s)?

**PHP code:**

```
<?
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];

$favouriteList = array("level_1","level_2","level_3","level_4","level_5",
"level_6","level_7","level_8","level_9","level_10","level_11","level_12",
"level_13","level_14","level_15","level_16","level_17","level_18", );

// if is not checked, zero out
if (!isset($_POST['checkBoxOne']))   {  $favouriteList[0] = ""; }
if (!isset($_POST['checkBoxTwo']))   {  $favouriteList[1] = ""; }
if (!isset($_POST['checkBoxThree'])) {  $favouriteList[2] = ""; }
if (!isset($_POST['checkBoxFour']))  {  $favouriteList[3] = ""; }
if (!isset($_POST['checkBoxFive']))  {  $favouriteList[4] = ""; }
if (!isset($_POST['checkBoxSix']))   {  $favouriteList[5] = ""; }
if (!isset($_POST['checkBoxSeven'])) {  $favouriteList[6] = ""; }
if (!isset($_POST['checkBoxEight'])) {  $favouriteList[7] = ""; }
if (!isset($_POST['checkBoxNine']))  {  $favouriteList[8] = ""; }
if (!isset($_POST['checkBoxTen']))   {  $favouriteList[9] = ""; }
if (!isset($_POST['checkBoxEleven'])){  $favouriteList[10] = "";}

/*$message = <<<EMAIl Hello $to. Your favourite POI list is : $favouriteList EMAIL;*/

$header = 'blabla@gmail.com';
$to = '$email';
$subject = 'Favourite POI List - Ghost Hunter Game';
$message = " Hello " . $name . "<br/>" . "Your favourite POI list is:" . "<br/>" . print_r(array_values($favouriteList));
mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

if($_POST) {
  if($name == '' || $email == ''){
    $emailMsg = "Please complete the form with your name and your email.";
  }
  else {
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
    $emailMsg = "Email sent successfully.";
  }
}
?>
```

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <title> Ghost Hunter </title>
      <link rel="icon" href="../img/ghost.png" type="image/x-icon">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1"/>
      <!-- JQUERY MOBILE CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
      <!-- Local CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/poilist.css">
      <!-- JQUERY MOBILE - Place here to be overwritten by local js -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
      <!-- LOCAL JS -->
      <script src="../js/poilist.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div data-role="page" id="poilist" data-theme="b">

        <div data-role="header">
          <h3> Choose level </h3>
          <a href="home.html"  data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="slideup"></a>
          <a href="#sendEmail" data-icon="mail" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="flip" data-position-to="window" data-rel="popup"> Send POI </a>
        </div> <!-- header -->

        <div data-role="content">

        <div id="emailMessage">
          <p id="emailMsg"> <?php echo $name; ?> </p>
        </div>

        <div data-role="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="level1.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="slide"> Level 1 </a></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox_lvl1"/></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="level2.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="slide"> Level 2 </a></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox_lvl2"/></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="level3.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="slide"> Level 3 </a></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox_lvl3"/></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="level4.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="slide"> Level 4 </a></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox_lvl4"/></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="level5.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="slide"> Level 5 </a></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox_lvl5"/></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="level6.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="slide"> Level 6 </a></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox_lvl6"/></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="level7.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="slide"> Level 7 </a></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox_lvl7"/></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="level8.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="slide"> Level 8 </a></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox_lvl8"/></li>
          </ul>
        </div> <!--navbar-->
      </div> <!--content-->

      <div data-role="popup" id="sendEmail">
        <!-- <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="b"></a> -->
        <form action="poilist.php" method="post">
          <h3> Send your Favourite Point of Interest </h3>
          <label for="name1 ">Name:</label>
          <input type="text"  placeholder="Your name"          name="name"  id="name1"/>
          <label for="email1">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" placeholder="youremail@gmail.com" name="email" id="email1"/>
          <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send email">
        </form>
      </div> <!--popup-->

    </div> <!--page-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure it isn't passing values. Put this in the top of your script and verify: `print_r( $_POST ); die();`

Comment: Could you add the relevant `html` code of the form to your question?

Comment: @Kenney I just found out that there is something wrong with my firebox browser. I tried in Google chrome and it works just fine.

Comment: @trincot I included the html.

Comment: I'm assuming you are getting the values for `name` and `email`, but not the checkboxes? If you do get them in Chrome then Chrome is not doing it right; only the inputs between `<form>` and `</form>` should be submitted. Also check the order of your code: *first* check if the name/email are not `empty()` in `$_POST`, and *then* process the form and send the email.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `<form action="poilist.php" method="post">` before *any* input, including you'r cheakboxes.

Comment: It does not work when I do that. I placed just before the <div data-role="navbar"> div.

Answer (score 0):

If this PHP page is named `poilist.php` then your `$_POST` variables should be set. Try removing the `action` attribute on the form since you are submitting back to the same page (If you don't specify an action, the form will submit back to the same page).

However, as @jNull noted, your check boxes will not be included in the post data unless they are part of the form being submitted.

PS. In this example you are missing your opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: I understand, but if I place my form tag outside the popup div it does not work when I click the button. Is there something to do with the jquery mobile framework ? I will remove the action attribute, but I just checked it works in chrome. There is something to do with my Firefox browser.

Comment: @KuJiM, the remark about `<?php` is an important one. Did you put that?

Comment: @KuJiM Yeah, I was having that problem as I was fiddling with it as well. If worse comes to worse you can add a click event to the submit button and add the checked checkboxes via javascript/jquery